# how to mixin react class arrow function

Tags: reactjs

I may not understand the `=>` in react component class. `handler` prints `true` in below code.

```
class X extends Component { 
     handler = () => {console.log(this instanceof X)} 

     render() { 
         return <a onClick={this.handler}>xxx</a> 
     } 
}
```

But I can't mixin `handler` in below code. `handler` always returns `false`. I want to know how to bind `this` in the `Object.assign`, so it can return `true` too. Thanks.

```
class X extends Component { 
     render() { 
         return <a onClick={this.handler}>xxx</a> 
     } 
} 
Object.assign(X.prototype, { 
     handler: () => {console.log(this instanceof X)} 
})
```

Comment: I know `=>` will automatically bind `this` for the `handler`. But I dont' know how to make it in the second code.

Comment: Use a regular function, not an arrow function. The arrow function will not be the context that you want: `handler() {console.log(this instanceof X)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow function are not meant to be used everywhere such as Constructor which can only be function !

The most common use case for arrow functions is "lambdas" which do not redefine this, often used as a callback to some function.

In your first example your arrow function will bind your context which is your class reference, so this instanceof X is true however :

```
Object.assign(X.prototype, { 
     handler: () => {console.log(this instanceof X)} 
})
```

Here you're trying to do the same but this, is no more your class but here your context will be window or something else..